# Play Framework: Limit number of concurrent requests

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-http

My Play router contains no logic but simply invokes this service class whose job is to invoke a URL, and process the response

```
class MyServiceImpl @Inject()(ws: WSClient)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends MyService with LazyLogging {
  val atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0)

  override def process(request: Request): Response = {
    val requestId = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet()
    logger.info(s"Received request $requestId")
    val futures: Seq[Future[String]] = request.records.map { record =>
      val future = {
        val response = ws.url("https://www.whatever.com").get()
        response.map(r => {
          r.status match {
            case 200 => {
              logger.info(s"Processed request ${requestId} ${atomicInteger.decrementAndGet()} remaining")
              "successful"
            }
            case other => {
              throw new RuntimeException(s"Returned response ${other}")
            }
          }
        })
      }
      future
    }
    Response(Future.sequence(futures))
  }
}
```

I am observing that under a high load the atomic integer will report 256 requests in flight. I am using the default Play dispatcher/execution contexts which I thought created a pool of one thread per core, and I have 8 cores on my machine.

How can I limit this to a much smaller number?

I have tried changing the Akka `default-dispatcher` and changing the Akka http `akka.http.server.max-connections` setting but it always continues to accept 256 requests.

Comment: Play is actually built to handle tons of requests and doesn't need a thread per request as other "old" sync frameworks/servers did in the past.

Comment: Do you really have a good reason to want to limit number of // requests ? What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: @GaëlJ The problem is that I've noticed that after the first request is returned, it will then accept another request which may in turn be processed before one of the original 256 requests. If I was to submit 1000 requests in quick succession, it is possible that request 900 is processed before request 100.

Comment: Sounds like you either want to build something that is not a HTTP endpoint (maybe more an event oriented system?) or you want to handle these requirements on the client side so that the client waits for response of 1st request before sending another one (assuming a single client)

Comment: No I'm afraid not, I want it to be a HTTP endpoint (similar to how a Spring MVC app may only handle 20~ requests at a time), if it's not possible with Play that is fine but I wanted to confirm that there was no way to achieve it with Play before I look at other options

Comment: Where does it get the 256 number from?

Comment: There are ways to handle it with Play but your requirements are kinda suspicious IMHO.

Comment: @GaëlJ good to hear...have you a few pointers on how to achieve it?

Comment: Within Play, the best way to enforce the ordering is to have the request handler send an ask to an actor which will process only one ask at a time.

Comment: Do you want to simply limit number of requests to the external HTTP service? Do you really care about ordering? As Levi pointed out, you will be better off introducing such limit in the service layer and there are multiple ways of doing it. To name few you can use akka actors or streams, a limited http connection pool, limited thread pool just in the service.